# What's this 'Bad Gateway' ad?

Tags: bug, support, ads

Now that [CR community ads work again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296348/197901), I'm frantically refreshing my browser trying to get to see my [Rubberduck ad](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7191/23788)... In 10 minutes I've seen the Brainduck ad 17 times, but none of my ducky.

Is this my ad?

[image: bad gateway]

If so, do I need to fix something?

Comment: Ugh, now I need to charge my phone :)

Comment: Did you try clicking it to see where/if it goes?

Comment: I'm adding the bug tag here because I don't think that a 502 should happen.

Comment: Or maybe this is a sign that Brainfuck is better than VBA?

Comment: Note to self: *frantically refreshing* a website is not a good idea. Rate. Limits.

Comment: Norepro on Windows 7 and Chrome (I saw it at least once).

Comment: Just saw the RD ad on CR, so... it's not my ad. I've no idea which ad it is though.

Comment: Is this still current? If not, we may want to put an answer on it stating it's no-repro closing the bug report.